# Can a Druid in Wild Shape cast the spells learned from the feats Telepathic and Telekinetic?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, druid, spellcasting, wild-shape

The spells that come with feats Telepathic and Telekinetic can be cast with no verbal, somatic, or material component requirement.  Would this mean that a wild shaped druid could cast these spells since all they would need is their mind to cast them?

Answer (score 22):

#### You cannot cast spells while in Wild Shape.

The feature description of [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167) says:

> You can’t cast spells [...]

So you cannot cast spells.

#### There is a way around this: cast them before using Wild Shape.

The rules for Wild Shape continue:

> Transforming doesn’t break your concentration on a spell you’ve already cast, however, or prevent you from taking actions that are part of a spell, such as call lightning, that you’ve already cast.

[*Mage hand*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand) and [*detect thoughts*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-thoughts) each have a duration of 1 minute, so you can continue to use them after you Wild Shape, as long as you cast them prior to using Wild Shape.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The 5e Druid's 'Wild Shape' feature lists, as one of its conditions, "You can't cast spells, ...."